# perceptron implementation, preocedure for post-feature vecor: bag-of-words model

Tags: machine-learning

I have code to generate feature vectors in the style of the bag-of-words model, you can see it on my [github page](https://github.com/h1395010/perceptron/blob/master/src/file_dict_createur/FileDictCreateur.java).

It renders output of the form:

```
/data/train/politics/p_0.txt, [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
/data/train/science/s_0.txt, [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
/data/train/atheism/a_0.txt, [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
/data/train/sports/s_1.txt, [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

I want to move on to the next step of the perceptron but I'm confused about what to do next. I guess the next thing I need to do is generate a feature vector for the 'test' data, isn't it?

For instance, in [this example](http://en.literateprograms.org/index.php?title=Special:DownloadCode/Perceptron_(Java)&oldid=19184) what is 'teachingOutput' supposed to be, training data vectors? Such as the ones I have above?

I also tried poking around in [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738277/perceptron-learning-most-important-feature) in an attempt to figure out what to do but, alas, to no avail.